# XPath with multiple predicates

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, predicates

I have a collection of plays and poems from different authors.  My XML looks like this:

```
<works>
    <editions>
       <edition>
           <playtitle>Henry IV, Part 1</playtitle>
           <playcode>1H4</playcode>
           <genre>play</genre>
           <metadataBlock>
               <meta content="Shakespeare, William" name="Creator"/>
           </metadataBlock>
       </edition>
    </editions>
</works>
```

I have used the following code successfully to extract the "playcode" from all the plays:

```
<xsl:when test="$only = 'plays'">
    <xsl:sequence select="/works/editions/edition[genre = 'play']/playcode"/>
</xsl:when>
```

However, I cannot figure it out how to extract the "playcode" from all the plays written by Shakespeare. I have tried multiple possibilities such as:

```
<xsl:when test="$only = 'plays'">
    <xsl:sequence select="/works/editions/edition[genre = 'play' 
        and @content='Shakespeare, William' 
        and @name='Creator']/playcode"/>
</xsl:when>
```

And such as:

```
<xsl:when test="$only = 'plays'">
      <xsl:sequence select="/works/editions/edition[genre =       
        'play']/playcode/metadataBlock/meta[@content='Shakespeare, William' 
           and@name='Creator']"/>
</xsl:when>
```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1):

In your first suggestion you try to evaluate *content* and *name* attributes of *edition* elements. Since they don't exist, the resulting sequence is empty. Thus, modify the XPath expression like this for example:

```
<xsl:when test="$only = 'plays'">
  <xsl:sequence select="/works/editions/edition[
    genre='play' and
    metadataBlock/meta[
      @content='Shakespeare, William' and
      @name='Creator'
    ]
  ]/playcode"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I would use keys -- both for convenience and efficiency**:

```
key('kPlaysByAuthor', 'Shakespeare, William')
```

**To select just the `playcode`:**

```
key('kPlaysByAuthor', 'Shakespeare, William')/playcode
```

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:key name="kPlaysByAuthor" match="edition"
      use="metadataBlock/meta[@name='Creator']/@content"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:copy-of select=
          "key('kPlaysByAuthor', 'Shakespeare, William')/playcode"/>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<works>
    <editions>
       <edition>
           <playtitle>Henry IV, Part 1</playtitle>
           <playcode>1H4</playcode>
           <genre>play</genre>
           <metadataBlock>
               <meta content="Shakespeare, William" name="Creator"/>
           </metadataBlock>
       </edition>
       <edition>
           <playtitle>Some Title</playtitle>
           <playcode>XYZ</playcode>
           <genre>play</genre>
           <metadataBlock>
               <meta content="Someone, Else" name="Creator"/>
           </metadataBlock>
       </edition>
    </editions>
</works>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<playcode>1H4</playcode>
```